# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' - using the Context API with nextJS 13.4

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, react-context

I'm new to nextJS and i'm trying to implement a simple searchbar to filter a list of posts and i'm using the context api to share the filter state between components. But i'm getting an error when trying to use the context hook inside my posts component.

i created a provider component, as recommended by the nextjs documentation and wrapped the application on the root layout, it seems that the problem is that i have a function which uses server side data fetching and therefore can't use 'use client' on the Posts component, where i'm calling that function, but then how can i share the filter state using the context api?

Providers.tsx file:

```
"use client";
import { FilterContextProvider } from "../store/FilterContext";
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Providers({ children }: Props) {
  return <FilterContextProvider>{children}</FilterContextProvider>;
}
```

The rootlayout.tsx:

```
import "./globals.css";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Providers from "./components/Providers";
import MyProfilePic from "./components/MyProfilePic";

export const metadata = {
  title: "João's blog",
  description: "created by me",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="h-screen bg-slate-800">
        <Providers>
          <Navbar />
          <MyProfilePic />
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

the Posts.tsx where i need to use the context to access the filter state:

```
import getFormattedDate from "@/lib/getFormattedDate";
import { getPostData, getSortedPostsData } from "@/lib/posts";
import Link from "next/link";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

export function generateStaticParams() {
  const posts = getSortedPostsData();
  return posts.map((post) => ({
    postId: post.id,
  }));
}

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { postId },
}: {
  params: { postId: string };
}) {
  const posts = getSortedPostsData();

  if (!posts.find((post) => post.id === postId)) {
    return {
      title: "Couldnt find post",
    };
  }

  return {
    title: postId,
    description: `This is a post about ${postId}`,
  };
}

export default async function Post({
  params: { postId },
}: {
  params: { postId: string };
}) {
  const posts = getSortedPostsData();

  if (!posts.find((post) => post.id === postId)) {
    return notFound();
  }

  const { title, date, contentHtml } = await getPostData(postId);
  const pubDate = getFormattedDate(date);

  return (
    <main className="px-6 prose prose-xl prose-slate dark:prose-invert mx-auto text-white">
      <h1 className="text-3xl mt-4 mb-0">{title}</h1>
      <p className="mt-0">{pubDate}</p>
      <article>
        <section dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: contentHtml }} />
        <p>
          <Link href="/">← Back to home</Link>
        </p>
      </article>
    </main>
  );
}
```

and the getSortedData function file which is throwing the error:

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import html from "remark-html";
import { remark } from "remark";

const postsDirectory = path.join(process.cwd(), "blogposts");

export function getSortedPostsData() {
  const fs = require("fs");
  // Get file names under /posts
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(postsDirectory);
  const allPostsData = fileNames.map((fileName: any) => {
    // Remove ".md" from file name to get id
    const id = fileName.replace(/\.md$/, "");

    // Read markdown file as string
    const fullPath = path.join(postsDirectory, fileName);
    const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, "utf8");

    // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
    const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

    const blogPost: BlogPost = {
      id,
      title: matterResult.data.title,
      date: matterResult.data.date,
    };

    // Combine the data with the id
    return blogPost;
  });
  // Sort posts by date
  return allPostsData.sort((a, b) => (a.date < b.date ? 1 : -1));
}
```